# Calculating area and perimeter of triangle with Python?

Tags: python

Hey guys I am having problems with outputting the area and perimeter of a triangle given the sides using the Heron's formula. Here's my code:

```
def main():

a = int(input('Enter first side: '))
b = int(input('Enter second side: '))
c = int(input('Enter third side: '))

def area():

    # calculate the sides
    s = (a + b + c) / 2

    # calculate the area
    area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5

    return area

area()

def perimeter():

    # Calculate the perimeter
    perim = a + b + c

    return perim

perimeter()


print( 'Area is: ',format(area,'.1f'))
print( 'Perimeter is: ',format(perim,',.1f'))


main()
```

I am getting lots of errors like

- TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.**format**
- NameError: name 'perim' is not defined

The way I'm supposed to do this is by asking for the sides in the main function and then calling the second one and then output the answers with one decimal place.

Can someone tell me what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the returned values and make the three side lengths global. Honestly, you should read more about variable scope which are the levels in which variables are defined. In addition, your variable names shouldn't overwrite your function names. In this way you can reuse those small functions later anywhere in your script by just calling them and passing three parameters.

For example:

```
def area(a, b, c):
    # calculate the sides
    s = (a + b + c) / 2
    # calculate the area
    area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5
    return area

def perimeter(a, b, c):
    # Calculate the perimeter
    perim = a + b + c
    return perim

def main():   
    a = int(input('Enter first side: '))
    b = int(input('Enter second side: '))
    c = int(input('Enter third side: '))

    print "Area is:", area(a, b, c)
    print "Perimeter is:", perimeter(a, b, c)

main()
```

This should be a cleaner way to do this and you only call one function from the main thread. You'll avoid declaring global variables and a whole lot of mess you have (no offence) in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the returned values and make the three side lengths global. Honestly, you should read more about variable scope which are the levels in which variables are defined. In addition, your variable names shouldn't overwrite your function names.

```
a = int(input('Enter first side: '))
b = int(input('Enter second side: '))
c = int(input('Enter third side: '))

def area():

    # calculate the sides
    s = (a + b + c) / 2

    # calculate the area
    area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5

    return area

areaValue = area()

def perimeter():

    # Calculate the perimeter
    perim = a + b + c

    return perim

perim = perimeter()


print( 'Area is: ', format(areaValue,'.1f'))
print( 'Perimeter is: ', format(perim,',.1f'))
```

Comment: `a = area()` wouldn't this be a problem, since `a` already exists?

Comment: True, thank you. I'll fix it. Otherwise, I am correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

- TypeError : be sure to mark formatting parameters with a pair of curly braces.

  ```
  'Area is {}, perimeter is {}.'.format(first_value, second_value)
  ```
- NameError : you might want to read about variable scopes.

  ```
  def perimeter(a, b, c):
      # Calculate the perimeter
      perim = a + b + c
      return perim

  # Call the function with the parameters
  # you want it to compute :
  print "Perimeter is {}."format(
      perimeter(3, 4, 5)
      )
  # output : "Perimeter is 12."
  ```